# Controller not passing variable correctly - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Could someone let me know why I get this error:

"Undefined variable: listings (View: \app\views\pages\listings.blade.php)"

**Controller**

```
class ListingsController extends BaseController {

    public function showListings() {
        $listings = Listing::paginate(10);
        return View::make('pages.listings', $listings);
    }

}
```

**View**

```
    <div class="container">

        <div id="main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span9">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Listings</h1>
                        @foreach($listings as $listing)
                            {{ $listing->address }}
                        @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @include('includes.footer')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing like this:

```
return View::make('pages.listings')->with('listings', $listings);
```

or

```
return View::make('pages.listings', array('listings' => $listings));
```

or even

```
return View::make('pages.listings', compact('listings'));
```

Comment: Or `return View::make('pages.listings', compact('listings'));` Or with PHP 5.4 `return View::make('pages.listings', ['listings' => $listings]);`. It's a little cleaner.

Comment: Thanks! I remember seeing it with the "with" statement in the Laravel Quick Start but the one I was following had it like in my question.

Comment: Every time you get stuck with something, it's better to take a look in the specific docs page for the command you're using: http://laravel.com/docs/responses. The basic stuff is usually there and it helps a lot.